# Effect of Covid-19 lockdowns on other diseases?

Tags: epidemiology

So I am sitting here at home in Covid-19 lock down. It got me wondering if there any prior evidence of the effects of lockdowns on the spread of others diseases? Or if there there are any solid conjectures on what happens?

I have only been able to find details on how lockdowns affect COVID-19 (and how long that will last). Not surprising since it is on the front of people's minds. I am looking for effects on secondary diseases.

Comment: What research or reasoning have you applied to the question?

Comment: @GrahamChiu Hmmm. Reasoning. I have reasoned that I can come up with all sorts of interesting ideas, but from past research have found it is better to get context and better understanding from those who are more knowledgeable than myself.

Comment: Well you should add that to your question to show some evidence of prior research.

Comment: @DarcyThomas We do require questions here to demonstrate some degree of prior research.